# How to record multiple transactions with GA's Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

When customers place orders on our system, they can be buying from one of several different "stores". We have a consolidated Shopping Cart experience, but split the transaction into individual orders as the final step.

I need some way to, on the final "thank you" page of the check out funnel, add products and record a transaction multiple times.

Does setting an action of "purchase" effectively clear the products so I can add more and repeat the process? For example...

```
ga('ec:addProduct', { 'id': '1' });
ga('ec:addProduct', { 'id': '2' });
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', { 'id': '123456' });
ga('ec:addProduct', { 'id': '3' });
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', { 'id': '987654' });
```

...In the above scenario, will Transaction 123456 contain products 1 & 2, while Transaction 987654 contains only product 3? Or, will Transaction 987654 contain products 1, 2, & 3?

Appreciate any insight into this!

Best,
Nate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split the transactions by sending an event between them, this hit will send all the information so you can start over with the next transaction.

```
ga('ec:addProduct', { 'id': '1' });
ga('ec:addProduct', { 'id': '2' });
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', { 'id': '123456' });

ga('send','event','whatever',{'non-interaction': 1});

ga('ec:addProduct', { 'id': '3' });
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', { 'id': '987654' });

ga('send','event','whatever',{'non-interaction': 1});
```